# horizontal slide of a view titanium

Tags: javascript, android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

[image]

I want to do something of this kind that when I swip to the left side, the white area moves to the left, and the red image appears. when it is normal the white area occupies the entire screen. How Can I Do This in Titanium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is default iOS behaviour and not Android, so I am going to point you to iOS documentation!

You can do it with both the TableView and ListView on iOS.

At the [ListView Documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ListView), there is a section `Editing Support`. This links to `canEdit` so you can enable the buttons, and also `editAction` so you can define which buttons you want to show up. This should get you started.

Something similar is also true for [TableView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView) but there you need to set `editable` to true. Functionality is a little bit more limited for TableView so I recommend using ListViews instead. Be aware this feature will then only be iOS 8+, which I also recommend setting as a minimum in your `tiapp.xml`

Comment: it works with tbleview after changing editable = tru. but now how can i change the size of the red delet button of the tableView and how can i change the text of the button?